# how to update column that has (NULL) value to 'A' in mysql

Tags: mysql, default

One of the column user_form in my table is filled with (NULL) value. Now i want to change 
that NULL to 'A' with this code `UPDATE table_name SET user_form='A' where user_form=(NULL)`
but no luck. I have also tried to ALTER column default value. But still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `is NULL` to check .[Detail](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

What manual says about `NULL` :

> Conceptually, `NULL` means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.

To test for `NULL`, use the `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators

```
UPDATE table_name SET user_form='A' where user_form is NULL
```

Comment: The reason you need to use "is NULL" is because NULL is defined as not being equal to anything, even itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET user_form='A' where user_form is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this using the **[IS NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/is-null-optimization.html)** instead of `=`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET user_form='A' 
where user_form is NULL
```

Also to note that you need IS NULL since NULL is not equal to anything so when you write `= NULL` then it is not logical

> NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat
>   differently from other values.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

UPDATE table_name SET user_form='A' where user_form IS NULL;